# Does Wind Demon card 648 cause it to attack twice if it can spend wind?

Tags: gloomhaven

Wind Demon card #648 shows a template attack and then says "[spend wind] +1 Attack [different template]". If wind is available to spend, does it make two attacks (one with the first template, the second with the larger template)? Or is the "spend wind" effect meant to modify the first attack (so it gets +1 attack and uses the larger template instead of the smaller)? It is not clear from the card and we cannot find clarification in the rule book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Wind Demon Attack Card]

The rules say

> Elemental infusions can be used to augment the effects of certain abilities.

So if wind is consumed the wind demon will perform move + 0 and Attack +1 with the greater AOE.

If it was to perform at attack again it would say Attack +X, If you look at this Cave Bear card for comparison which has two attacks.

[image: Cave Bear card]

Comment: Re "*If it was to perform at attack again it would say Attack +X*", Succinctly, *Attack X* and *Attack +X* add an attack action, while *+X Attack* adds to an existing attack action.